# Please explain me why i am getting this error in snakemake? I´ve been strugling for days please advise me on whats going wrong

Tags: python, pipeline, wildcard, snakemake, rna-seq

I wrote this pipeline in snakemake to process my fastq files and get the raw counts but for some reason that I don't understand in the last rule (featurecounts) I get this error:

> WildcardError in line 175 of /mnt/c/Users/manso/Desktop/hel/pe.py:
> Wildcards in input files cannot be determined from output files: 'sample'

Other rules use the same input as featureCounts rule so I don't understand why it returns this error for that specific rule.

I'd really appreciate your help.

Here is my snakefile:

```
(SAMPLE,FRR) = glob_wildcards("rawReads/{sample}_{frr}.fastq.gz")

rule all:
    input:
        #raw_FASTQC
        expand("rawQC/fastqc/{sample}_{frr}_fastqc.html", sample=SAMPLE, frr=FRR),
        expand("rawQC/fastqc/{sample}_{frr}_fastqc.zip", sample=SAMPLE, frr=FRR),
        #raw_MultiQC
        "rawQC/multiqc_report.html",
        #FASTP
        expand("trimmedReads/{sample}_1.fastq.gz", sample=SAMPLE),
        expand("trimmedReads/{sample}_2.fastq.gz", sample=SAMPLE),
        expand("trimmedReads/{sample}_fastp_report.html", sample=SAMPLE),        
        #trimmed_FASTQC
        expand("trimmedQC/fastqc/{sample}_{frr}_fastqc.html", sample=SAMPLE, frr=FRR),
        expand("trimmedQC/fastqc/{sample}_{frr}_fastqc.zip", sample=SAMPLE, frr=FRR),
        #trimmed_MultiQC
        "trimmedQC/multiqc_report.html",
        #get fa and gtf files
        "genome/Homo_sapiens.GRCh38.dna_sm.primary_assembly.fa",
        "genome/Homo_sapiens.GRCh38.106.gtf.gz",
        #HISAT2_index
        ["index."  + str(i) + ".ht2" for i in range(1,9)],
        #HISAT_align
        expand("aligned/{sample}.bam", sample=SAMPLE),
        #samtools
        expand("aligned/{sample}.sorted.bam", sample=SAMPLE),
        expand("samtools_stats/{sample}.stats.txt", sample=SAMPLE),
        expand("samtools_stats/{sample}.flagstat.txt", sample=SAMPLE),
        #rawCounts
        "raw_Counts"


rule raw_FASTQC:
    input:
        "rawReads/{sample}_{frr}.fastq.gz",
    output:
        html="rawQC/fastqc/{sample}_{frr}_fastqc.html",
        zip= "rawQC/fastqc/{sample}_{frr}_fastqc.zip", # the suffix _fastqc.zip is necessary for multiqc to find the file. If not using multiqc, you are free to choose an arbitrary filename
    params: "--quiet"
    log:
        "logs/fastqc/{sample}_{frr}.log"
    threads: 16
    wrapper:
        "v1.7.0/bio/fastqc"


rule raw_MultiQC:
    input:
        expand("rawQC/fastqc/{sample}_{frr}_fastqc.zip", sample=SAMPLE, frr=FRR),
    params:
        path="rawQC/fastqc"
    output:
       "rawQC/multiqc_report.html"
    shell:
        "multiqc --force -n {output} {params.path}" 


rule FASTP:
    input:
         read1="rawReads/{sample}_1.fastq.gz",
         read2="rawReads/{sample}_2.fastq.gz",
    output:
        trimmed1="trimmedReads/{sample}_1.fastq.gz",
        trimmed2="trimmedReads/{sample}_2.fastq.gz",
        report_html= "trimmedReads/{sample}_fastp_report.html",
    threads: 16
    shell:
         " fastp --thread {threads} -i {input.read1} -I {input.read2} -o {output.trimmed1} -O {output.trimmed2} -h {output.report_html} "


rule trimmed_FASTQC:
    input:
        "trimmedReads/{sample}_{frr}.fastq.gz"
    output:
        html="trimmedQC/fastqc/{sample}_{frr}_fastqc.html", 
        zip="trimmedQC/fastqc/{sample}_{frr}_fastqc.zip",  # the suffix _fastqc.zip is necessary for multiqc to find the file. If not using multiqc, you are free to choose an arbitrary filename
    params: "--quiet"
    log:
        "logs/fastqc/{sample}_{frr}.log"
    threads: 16
    wrapper:
        "v1.7.0/bio/fastqc"
        

rule trimmed_MultiQC:
    input:
        expand("trimmedQC/fastqc/{sample}_{frr}_fastqc.zip", sample=SAMPLE, frr=FRR),
    params:
        path="trimmedQC/fastqc"
    output:
       "trimmedQC/multiqc_report.html"
    shell:
        "multiqc --force -n {output} {params.path} "


#Get annotation GTF
rule get_genome_gtf:
    "Downloading Genome annotation file from Ensemble, Homo sapiens primary assembly (GRCh38)"
    output:
        gtf = "genome/Homo_sapiens.GRCh38.106.gtf.gz"
    shell:
        "cd genome"
        " && wget ftp://ftp.ensembl.org/pub/release-106/gtf/homo_sapiens/Homo_sapiens.GRCh38.106.gtf.gz"
        " && gunzip -k Homo_sapiens.GRCh38.106.gtf.gz "


# Get genome fa
rule get_genome_fa:
    "Downloading Genome sequence, Homo sapiens primary assembly (GRCh38)"
    output:
        fa = "genome/Homo_sapiens.GRCh38.dna_sm.primary_assembly.fa"
    shell:
        "cd genome"
        " && wget ftp://ftp.ensembl.org/pub/release-106/fasta/homo_sapiens/dna/Homo_sapiens.GRCh38.dna_sm.primary_assembly.fa.gz"
        " && gunzip -k Homo_sapiens.GRCh38.dna_sm.primary_assembly.fa "


rule HISAT2_index:
    input:
        fa = rules.get_genome_fa.output.fa
    output:
        ["index." + str(i) + ".ht2" for i in range(1,9)],
    message:
        "indexing genome"
    threads: 16
    shell:
        " hisat2-build -p {threads} {input.fa} index --quiet"


rule HISAT2_align:
    input:
        read1=rules.FASTP.output.trimmed1,
        read2=rules.FASTP.output.trimmed2,
        index=rules.HISAT2_index.output
    output:
        bam="aligned/{sample}.bam",
        metrics="logs/{sample}_HISATmetrics.txt"
    threads: 16
    shell:
        " hisat2 --threads {threads} -x index -1 {input.read1} -2 {input.read2} 2> {output.metrics}"
        " | samtools view -Sbh -o {output.bam} "


rule samtools_sort:
    input:
        aligned=rules.HISAT2_align.output.bam
        #"aligned/{sample}.bam"
    output:
        "aligned/{sample}.sorted.bam"
    threads: 8 
    shell:
       "samtools sort {input.aligned} -o {output}"


rule samtools_stats:
    input:
        "aligned/{sample}.sorted.bam",
    output:
        "samtools_stats/{sample}.stats.txt",
    shell:
       "samtools stats {input} > {output} "

rule samtools_flagstat:
    input:
        "aligned/{sample}.sorted.bam",
    output:
        "samtools_stats/{sample}.flagstat.txt",
    shell:
        "samtools flagstat {input} > {output} "
        

rule featureCounts:
    input:
        samples="aligned/{sample}.sorted.bam",   
        gtf=rules.get_genome_gtf.output.gtf
    output:
        "raw_Counts"
    threads:
        16
    shell:
        "featureCounts -T {threads} -a {input.gtf} -o {output} {input.samples}"
´´´
```

Comment: Line 175 needs comma in the end of the line to separate the inputs.

Comment: Yes, sorry just corrected that. The error is still the same: 
Wildcards in input files cannot be determined from output files:
'sample'

Comment: Please correct your title to something that identifies the problem rather than expressing your frustration. "I've been struggling..." is not a very descriptive search term.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Snakemake uses pattern in the output to infer which inputs to use. In the last rule, output is `raw_Counts`, which gives no indication of what to use for `{sample}` wildcard. Changing it to something like this might work for your use case:

```py
rule featureCounts:
    input:
        samples="aligned/{sample}.sorted.bam",   
        gtf=rules.get_genome_gtf.output.gtf
    output:
        "raw_Counts_{sample}.txt"
```

This will require adding the expanded version to rule `all`:

```py
    # add this target to rule all
    expand("raw_Counts_{sample}.txt", sample=SAMPLE),
```

Edit: if this rule is intended as an aggregate, then in the input directive you will want to remove wildcard search by substituting all the values.

```py
rule featureCounts:
    input:
        samples=expand("aligned/{sample}.sorted.bam", sample=SAMPLE),   
        gtf=rules.get_genome_gtf.output.gtf
    output:
        "raw_Counts"
```

Edit 2: note that `glob_wildcards` does not return unique values for each  wildcard, but rather the wildcards associated with each globbed file. If you want unique values, then one easy way to achieve that is to convert `SAMPLE` to a set (specifically for this rule).

```py
rule featureCounts:
    input:
        samples=expand("aligned/{sample}.sorted.bam", sample=set(SAMPLE)),   
        gtf=rules.get_genome_gtf.output.gtf
    output:
        "raw_Counts"
```

Comment: But the output for that rule is only one file that contains a matrix of the counts for all of the samples. I don't want 100 count files since I have 100 samples.

Comment: OK thank you so much it does work now. 
However, the input is iterating 2 times over each sample... why is that?


```rule featureCounts:
    input: aligned/ERR1024550.sorted.bam, aligned/ERR1024550.sorted.bam, aligned/ERR999703.sorted.bam, aligned/ERR999703.sorted.bam, aligned/SRR11080823.sorted.bam, aligned/SRR11080823.sorted.bam, aligned/SRR11080824.sorted.bam, aligned/SRR11080824.sorted.bam, genome/Homo_sapiens.GRCh38.106.gtf.gz
    output: raw_Counts
    jobid: 42
    resources: tmpdir=/tmp
```

Comment: Thank you for the 2nd edit it's working exactly how I want now!